# Existing tools built on gmail APIs providing local mirroring, IMAP, and SMTP daemon?

Tags: gmail-api

Is there yet a tool built atop the gmail API which would:

- Build and run as a daemon on macos and linux
- Sync a local mail store, built atop postgres, from its
    authoritative representation in gmail. The sync should rebuild
    efficiently from source in the event that the local copy is
    destroyed or corrupted.
- Provide a sane and accessible postgres schema for mail so I can
    connect directly via `psql` or other tools and query mail directly,
    filtering by headers and bodies (attachments search not so important, though they should of course be stored locally)
- Provide an IMAP and SMTP server on localhost to be mutt's interface to the
    postgres mailstore, and to send mail through the gmail API.

I currently use `mutt` as my MUA, and would continue to do so, but would prefer a tool like the one I described so I can use it to replace my combination of `fetchmail` + `procmail` + `msmtp` for the underpinnings, as well as the attendant maze of configuration files.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: I can't think of anything more to provide in terms of a problem statement. I'm going to build my own version of the tool I describe above using the gmail APIs, but before I invest the time, and since there is no other official gmail API users' list AFAICT, I'm asking here to see if someone has already built what I need.